# Prolog Smart Graph Algorithm

Tags: prolog

I am a university student who is being taught Prolog. I am only 3 weeks into the course and this is my first assignment.

The goal of the assignment is to create a graph searching algorithm that returns a path from goal to end and remembers that certain nodes are not reachable from specific nodes. The base code we must have is:

```
street(genoa,turin).
street(genoa,busalla).
street(milan,turin).
street(milan,rome).
street(milan,genoa).
street(genoa,rome).
street(rome,napoli).
actionStreet(A,B):- street(A,B); street(B,A).
giveSolution(actionStreet,genoa,X,Steps).
```

The first part of the assignment is to create a graph solving algorithm that does not have the destination in the solution more than once and I believe this code does this:

```
street(genoa,turin). 
street(genoa,busalla).
street(milan,turin).
street(milan,rome).
street(milan,genoa).
street(genoa,rome).
street(rome,napoli).

actionStreet(A,B):- street(A,B);street(B,A).
isConnected(P,A,B):-call(P,A,B).
giveSolution(P,Start,End,Steps):-trip(P,Start,End,[Start],Steps).
trip(P,Node,Node,_,[Node]).
trip(P,Start,Finish,Visited,[Start|Path]):-
 isConnected(P,Start,X),
 not(member(X,Visited)),
 trip(P,X,Finish,[X|Visited]).
```

So the bit I am stuck on is that to solve the overall problem you need to keep track of certain nodes that are unreachable from specific nodes. I think this can be done using a dynamic database, that stores the nodes and the other node that is not reachable from the first node.

Therefore when the `trip(P,Start,Finish,Visited,[Start|Path]):-` predicate fails, the node `X` and the node `End` being looked at should be put in the database. I thought this could be done by using this change to the `trip(P,Start,Finish,Visited,[Start|Path]):-` predicate code:

```
trip(P,Start,Finish,Visited,[Start|Path]):-
 (isConnected(P,Start,X),
 not(member(X,Visited)),
 trip(P,X,Finish,[X|Visited])-> true;assert(cannot(X,Finish))).
```

However, the if then predicate does not work in the way it would in Java. Can someone please help and explain why this code fragment does not do exactly what the first version does, except add to the database if those conditions are fail?

Answer (score 0):

You are inverting the 'logical truth' of your predicate. that is, when the original trip/5 succeeded, now it's failing, and when it was failing, it now succeeds and remember `cannot(X,Finish)`.  And X should be uninstantiated at that point...

Controlling execution flow of Prolog can be tricky, since it may depend on the presence of other clauses, where they are located, what these clauses do... I don't claim much merit on this clue

Comment: Sorry, it is meant to be true, not fail. I am editing it now.

Comment: @AgitoGilgamesh12: seems bad practice to me removing bugs from the code posted, after an answer has given a clue, and don't acknowledge it...

Comment: That was not meant to be there to begin with. I had copied an earlier version of my code.